# Getting single data from a JSON response with a data from a cell

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a sheet an excel where I have a table with column `[ID]` `[NAME]` `[GENDER]`. Of these three columns, I want to fill only the first column, while the other two should get the data using a web request.

To be more precise, and to simplify this question, suppose to use the Studio Ghibli API to get a person info: `https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/<<person_id>>`. This API returns something like this:

```
{
  "id": "986faac6-67e3-4fb8-a9ee-bad077c2e7fe",
  "name": "Satsuki Kusakabe",
  "gender": "Female",
  "age": "11",
  "eye_color": "Dark Brown/Black",
  "hair_color": "Dark Brown",
  "films": [
    "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films/58611129-2dbc-4a81-a72f-77ddfc1b1b49"
  ],
  "species": "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/species/af3910a6-429f-4c74-9ad5-dfe1c4aa04f2",
  "url": "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/986faac6-67e3-4fb8-a9ee-bad077c2e7fe"
}
```

So, what I want to have is this table:
| ID | Name | Gender |
| - | - | - |
| 986faac6-67e3-4fb8-a9ee-bad077c2e7fe | | |
| d5df3c04-f355-4038-833c-83bd3502b6b9 | | |

And now, supposing the ID `986faac6-67e3-4fb8-a9ee-bad077c2e7fe` is placed in cell A1, in the `[NAME]` column I'd like to call the request `https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/{A1}`, and taking the value of the `name` property. So, writing something like this:
`=WebRequest(https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/<<A1>>).gender`

Of course, I  know that expression is not valid, but I wonder if I can do something like that.

I've found something, like using "Get data from Web", in "Data" tab, but I could not get what I wanted, probably because I did not understand correctly how to use that.

Finally, if possible I'd like to NOT use macro of VB.NET. But, if that's the only thing possible.. Well, I'll adapt.

Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel formulas to parse JSON from `WebService` are complicated and not easily modified.  In addition, you would have to execute a separate web query for each id.

I think simpler would be to do the whole thing in Power Query (get data from web).

- Create a list of your desired ID's in some range
- Make this a **Table** and **Name** it `idTbl`
- Use PQ to download the whole database (it's not very large), then just select the id's of interest.

For example:

**M Code**

```
let

//download them all
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "name", "gender"}, {"id", "name", "gender"}),

//get list of the desired ID's
    idList = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="idTbl"]}[Content],

//get just those on the list
    joined = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Column1","id",idList,"id","joined",JoinKind.RightOuter),

//remove unneeded column
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(joined,{"joined"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

***note that the results can go on a different page***

Comment: Thanks. Though, two questions: (1) can the ID table and the table from Power Query being.. the same Table? (2) You wrote "download the whole database", but the Studio Ghibli was just an example: the real work is on a stock databases, which is pretty huge (I have used Studio Ghibli because they are open and don't require any Key)

Comment: @Jolly 1. You could, I guess, put the last two output columns of the PQ next to the ID table, but I think it would be simpler (and more easily maintained) to keep them separate (on a different worksheet).  PQ can handle pretty large databases. But if the stock database API can handle returning multiple stock quotes with a single call, there's no reason why you couldn't construct your web call that way, appending the ID column to the webcall after properly structuring it.  In general, though, you should try to do this with a single webcall instead of one call per item.